# Airflow BigQueryGetDataOperator does not return an iterable (8.4.0)

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Using Airflow 2.4.2, apache-airflow-google-providers 8.4.0. According to https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/8.4.0/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery.BigQueryGetDataOperator the operator should be returning a list.

But my basic DAG when loaded locally in the UI is given me a DAG import error with `TypeError: 'BigQueryGetDataOperator' object is not iterable`.

```
fetch_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
    task_id='fetch_data',
    dataset_id='my_dataset',
    table_id='my_table',
    project_id='my-project-id',
    max_results=100,
    selected_fields='somecols',
    gcp_conn_id='my_conn_id',
)

for i, data in enumerate(fetch_data):
    ....
```

Comment: OK, I think I just realized my mistake. I was expecting the operator to run like a regular Python function and return a list but I need to run it as an Airflow operator and then probably use xcom to push it somewhere

Answer (score 0):

get_data is a task and to get its output you need to pull its "return_value" with Xcom.

for example echo the output with bash command:

```
BashOperator(
        task_id="get_data_result",
        bash_command=f"echo {{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data', key='return_value') }}}}",
    )
```